# Django Python: Display Different Views for Different User Types by Retrieving Data in Wamp Server

Tags: python, mysql, django, types, multiple-users

I am newbie and I really need help in this problem. 
Can someone answer this and teach me how to do it in Django.

I want to create a restaurant system which has 4 types of users (admin, customer, kitchen, and cashier) in Django. I already created MySQL user database by using Wamp Server. Meanwhile, I want to create a different views for each users. Is it possible to retrieve the data from MySQL for user login purpose and assign the different views for user login page in Django?

I really need the helps. Thank you.